# Unparseable date while loading Play2 assets

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Can someone please explain me why I have these runtime errors with Play2 (scala).
This happens at the beginning, and after some F5 it doesn't appear anymore.
It appears on assets loading (css/js...)

```
[error] application - 

! @6da5355eh - Internal server error, for request [GET /assets/js/backbone/collections/singleStample.js] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[ParseException: Unparseable date: "jeu., 07 f?vr. 2013 17:21:24 UTC"]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "jeu., 07 f?vr. 2013 17:21:24 UTC"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Assets.scala:80) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:na]
    at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Assets.scala:80) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:na]
    at scala.Option.filterNot(Option.scala:162) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Assets.scala:80) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:na]
    at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Assets.scala:79) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:na]


[error] application - 

! @6da5355eg - Internal server error, for request [GET /assets/js/backbone/views/application/appView.js] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.text.DigitList.fitsIntoLong(DigitList.java:229) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1314) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:2089) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1455) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_01]
    at controllers.Assets$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Assets.scala:80) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:na]
```

My route to load the assets is:

```
GET     /assets/*file                               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

The `controllers.Assets` is provided by the framework, I didn't do anything fancy myself like trying to parse a date or manipulating an array, I just followed the documentation...

The request header is:

```
GET /assets/js/backbone/collections/singleStample.js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/15.0.874.106 Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: gs_u=1379104331:71067:61092:1360004387267; PLAY_SESSION=061323e1e5a413f5d193181ea78e640db8d947ee-user%3A5087de9be4b078ca9f03f224; mp_dfe43e2fceb459410656de3c4f3ae169_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2213c82cf24b5df-0cdabcd37-5d772518-15f900-13c82cf24b71003%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D
If-None-Match: "a588b22a3fc3967daefa02e1843b00d296f77806"
If-Modified-Since: jeu., 07 f?vr. 2013 17:21:24 UTC
```

I don't know why there is this "?" in `If-Modified-Since: jeu., 07 f?vr. 2013 17:21:24 UTC`.
What I can tell you is that I use Chromium on Ubuntu but this also appears on someone using a Macbook

Can someone give me some insight?

Comment: My bet goes to the diacritic in 'février'. Pure guessing thought. In your place i'd have look at the sources where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: please take a look at my edit @pedrofurla

Comment: What's your Play version ? 2.0, 2.1 ?

Comment: nico_ekito: play 2.0.2

Comment: yes it is 2.0.2, is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it is a Play 2.0.2 bug that is resolved in Play 2.0.3